# Channel Specific Shipping based on Quantity Threshold

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

I have a site where I have 2 product channels: one for webinar registrations, the other for physical products to ship (and in the future we will offer digital downloads so I'll be creating a channel for that)

As shipping settings are site-wide, I can't simply enable quantity specific shipping for just the physical products. However I know you can specify Shipping Per Item and I can create a field for that.

However, how would that field be set up if the shipping rules are:

- **Qty** 1-2 $10
- **Qty** 3-5 $20
- **Qty** 6+ $35

I can create a matrix field of 2 columns, I guess, with these details, but how can CartThrob automatically figure out that there's 2 of this particular item and only add shipping for THAT item based on that quantity?

And ONLY for this channel. Other channels are automatically zero shipping because a) registration and b) digital download.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing Lea - just make sure that when each of the items in the other (non-physical) channels get added to the cart, they have the [shipping_exempt](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/index.html#shipping_exempt) parameter (I believe this parameter used to be called `no_shipping`) set to `yes`. They will then be excluded from the quantity-based shipping calculations.

Comment: So basically, I should set a site wide quantity setting for shipping and then for the channels/entries that don't have shipping, I'll add the shipping_exempt parameter?

Comment: That is correct.